# Host url is showing as encrypted in spring boot logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url, host, httpconnection

I am trying to make a host connectivity with my spring boot, when i check the logs whether url is correct or not. The url is showing in encrypted format. Can you guys help this out to me.

Comment: can you share the logs ? what is your logging configuration ?

Comment: Connecting URL : https:&amp;#x2F;&amp;#x2F;12.4.18.52&amp;#x2F;r1&amp;#x2F;users?wsdl


im getting like this instead of https://12.4.18.52/r1/users?wsdl

Comment: and how do you configure your logging ? you should put the details to question not in comment.